# Custom jQuery plugin only targeting specific container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So I'm writing a jQuery tabs plugin which I can re-use it across my site. Below is the HTML:

```
    <div class="js-tabs">
    <div id="top-text">Top 10 Best</div>

    <ul class="top-side-tabs">
        <li id="selected">
            <a id="day" data-url="/top/day">Today</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="week" data-url="/top/week">Week</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="month" data-url="/top/month">Month</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="year" data-url="/top/year">Year</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="top-text">
        <div class="js-tabs-container">
            <div class="loading">Loading...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the plugin itself:

```
(function($) {
var tabs = {        
    fn: function(params) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $thisContainer = $(this);
            $contentContainer = $thisContainer.find('.js-tabs-container').first();
            var $thisUl = $thisContainer.find('ul').first();
            var $thisLi = $thisUl.children('li');

            var tabs = [];
            var tabUrls = [];

            $thisLi.each(function() {
                $links = $(this).children('a').attr('id');
                tabs.push($links);

            });

            // Display first url in the container when page first loads
            var firstTabUrl = $thisUl.find('li > a').first().data('url');
            //console.log(firstTabUrl);
            $.ajax({
                url: firstTabUrl,
                cache: false,
                success: function(content) {
                    $contentContainer.empty().append(content).hide().fadeIn(500);
                    $('.loading').hide();
                }
            });

            // Add click event handler for each tab
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                var id = i;
                $('#' + tabs[i]).bind('click', (function(id) {
                    return function() {
                        // Grab tab's url from data attribute
                        var tabUrl = $(this).data('url');
                        // Find the js-tabs-container
                        // This is what we're changing
                        if (tabs.length) {
                            $('.loading').show();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: tabUrl,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(content) {
                                    $contentContainer.empty().append(content).hide().fadeIn(500);
                                    $('.loading').hide();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                })(id));
            }

        });
    }
}
    $.fn.tabs = tabs.fn
})(jQuery);

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.js-tabs').tabs();
});
```

Ignoring the fact that I am using some unique div ids, if I copy that HTML code more than once, I expect it to work independently of the other one.

What is happening is:

A)

```
Top 10 Best | Today | Week | Month | Year
[.js-tabs-container]
```

B)

```
Top 10 Best | Today | Week | Month | Year
[.js-tabs-container]
```

Say I click on "Week" in `A` above, the content in `B` will be repopulated. It also looks like it's going through .each() more than once (as it fades in and out twice). On top of that, if you click on any of the options within `B`, it simply won't work.

I'm new to this style of plugin development to keep everything in its own namespace, so I might be overlooking something major, so any help would be great.

Also, any advice on how to re-factor this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using the same id twice (top-text) in your markup, which is known to generally cause problems with the selector-engine, if your $(this) represents one of those, it can cause your plugin to never access the second div. IDs should be unique

Comment: @Semyazas Yeah, I just threw it up there as an example. Turns out I left out var for $thisContainer and $contentContainer, which I'm not sure why I did that. Although it now solves the issue I was having :D

Answer (score 0):

Ended up leaving out `var` as the prefix for $thisContainer and $contentContainer. Should work fine now:

```
(function($) {
var tabs = {
    fn: function(params) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $thisContainer = $(this);
            var $contentContainer = $thisContainer.find('.js-tabs-container').first();
            var $thisUl = $thisContainer.find('ul').first();
            var $thisLi = $thisUl.children('li');

            var tabs = [];

            $thisLi.each(function() {
                $links = $(this).children('a').attr('id');
                tabs.push($links);

            });

            // Display first url in the container when page first loads
            var firstTabUrl = $thisUl.find('li > a').first().data('url');

            $.ajax({
                url: firstTabUrl,
                cache: false,
                success: function(content) {
                    $contentContainer.empty().append(content).hide().fadeIn(500);
                    $('.loading').hide();
                }
            });

            // Add click event handler for each tab
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                var id = i;
                $('#' + tabs[i]).bind('click', (function(id) {
                    return function() {
                        // Grab tab's url from data attribute
                        var tabUrl = $(this).data('url');
                        // Find the js-tabs-container
                        // This is what we're changing
                        if (tabs.length) {
                            $('.loading').show();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: tabUrl,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(content) {
                                    $contentContainer.empty().append(content).hide().fadeIn(500);
                                    $('.loading').hide();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                })(id));
            }

        });
    }
}
$.fn.tabs = tabs.fn
})(jQuery);

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.js-tabs').tabs();
});
```